# Xamarin.Forms.Android black screen in release mode playing back HLS video with linking set to "SDK assemblies only"

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, libvlcsharp

In my Xamarin.Forms.Android app I'm trying to playback a HLS video encoded with azure media services.

This works in debug mode.
But when I run in **release** mode I see the following problem:

- the video does seem to load, and it starts playback (the slider moves) but the screen remains black.
  Since my video did not have audio i'm not sure if audio worked.

I tried to fix release mode by setting my android project linker settings from "Sdk Assemblies Only" to "none" and this seemed to do the trick, playback worked in release mode when pushing it to an attached device.

To reproduce the problem in debug mode I had to both

- set the linker to "SDK assemblies only"
- set the Code shrinker to r8

I then saw the following output:

[VLC] [00000074f8240e90/4256] libvlc window: AndroidNativeWindow jni init failed
[VLC] [00000074f8240e90/4256] libvlc window: InitJNIFields failed
[VLC] [00000075175fdc90/4258] libvlc vout display: parent window not available
[VLC] [00000074f385e990/4256] libvlc video output: video output creation failed
[VLC] [00000074edff459003-04 13:35:46.832 E/VLC     (15716): [00000075001e6890/4256] libvlc decoder: failed to create video output
[VLC] [00000075001e6890/4256] libvlc decoder: Opaque Vout request failed
[VLC] [00000074f8241750/4259] libvlc window: AndroidNativeWindow jni init failed
[VLC] [00000074f8241750/4259] libvlc window: InitJNIFields failed
[VLC] [000000751fe4ba90/4260] libvlc vout display: parent window not available
[VLC] [0000007517212f90/4259] libvlc video output: video output creation failed
[VLC] [00000075001e6890/4259] libvlc decoder: failed to create video output
[VLC] [00000074fcef7590/425a] libvlc window: AndroidNativeWindow jni init failed
[VLC] [00000074fcef7590/425a] libvlc window: InitJNIFields failed
[VLC] [00000075175fe890/4261] libvlc vout display: parent window not available

This leads me to the conclusion that there is code that is stripped out by the linker that the vlc media player needs in order to playback my stream. However the the documentation does not state anything is needed to fix the linker.

I am using

- Windows 10
- Visual studio 16.9.0
- LibVLCSharp.Forms v3.4.9 in my XF android and master XF project
- VideoLAN.LibVLC.Android v3.2.0 in my XF android project

when searching for the error codes I came across this issue https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/255 which seems to address the problem. Will post an update if this fixes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the solution was as mentioned in the issue to:

> - Add a file to your Xamarin.Android app root named "r8.cfg"
> - in the properties set Build Action to "ProguardConfiguration".
> - In this file add lines:

```
-keep class org.videolan.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.videolan.**
```